# How to properly import external javascript file?

Tags: javascript, import, custom-element, home-assistant

In accordance with Home Assistant [documentation](https://developers.home-assistant.io/docs/frontend/custom-ui/custom-card/), I should import external javascript files like below -

```
import "https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=1&module";
```

but when I do so I get the following error -

```
?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=1&module:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'performance')
at ymapsInit (?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=1&module:1:84)
at ?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=1&module:1:28837
```

the error leads to the following code -

```
(function ymapsInit(e) {
    var n = this
      , t = {
        ns: {},
        supports: {},
        env: e
    };
    t.performance = {
        now: n.performance && n.performance.now ? n.performance.now.bind(n.performance) : function() {
            return Date.now()
        }
    },
```

Since this is external code, I can not modify it.
[Here](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_driving) is the working example of the same code, but not within Home Assistant.

How could I fix it?

Comment: The external code is meant to run in sloppy mode, and you're running your code in strict mode?

Comment: @Teemu, I don't know how it works within Home Assistant :(. What should I try?